# Change element style on hover of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
   <div> class="module-title" 
     <h2 class="title" style="visibility: visible;">
         <span>Spantext</span> 
         Nonspantext
    </h2>
   </div>
```

What I want to do is to hover over the h2 element and both of the spantext and nonspantext to change color. My limitation is that I cannot put the Nonspantext inside span tags (I cannot change the HTML code at all).

The problem is that when I put the CSS rule

```
.title :hover {color:#D01A13;}
```

only the spantext changes color on hover and when I put the code

```
.module-title :hover {color:#D01A13;}
```

the nonspantext will change color if I hover over the spantext but I also want the opposite to happen.

I am aware of the '+' and '~' rules in CSS but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.title:hover {
    color:#D01A13;
}
```

Spaces matter in CSS. The space is the "children" operator, so `.title :hover` means "when any children of `.title` are hovered over." Text nodes don't count as children.

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AW2pM/)

---

Re your comment:

> Ok, this code is good, I did not know about spaces in CSS. But, forgot to mention that there is also a rule .title span {color:#888888 !important;} that complicates the things a little bit. If I cannot change this rule, is there any chance that the .title can change color on hover?

Sure, you could try

```
.title:hover, .title:hover span {
    color:#D01A13 !important;
}
```

Of course, this is very ugly. This is why you should use `!important` as little as possible. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AW2pM/1/)

Comment: Ok, this code is good, I did not know about spaces in CSS.
But, forgot to mention that there is also a rule

.title span {color:#888888 !important;}

that complicates the things a little bit. If I cannot change this rule, is there any chance that the .title can change color on hover?

Comment: Spot on answer. If you'd like to understand and see some of the differences in how it works, I've also modified Doorknob's fiddle to add .title:hover span { } and .title span:hover { }, to highlight how you can stack these elements in various ways. http://jsfiddle.net/HT9rd/

Answer (score -1):

jQuery approach to doing this, by wrapping inner content within another div and applying style to that div:

```
$('h2.title').wrapInner('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

Than just apply css styling to `.wrapper` if need be.

Comment: Didn't catch the space after that, better to use Doorknob's answer.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The OP wants the color to change on **hover**, not all the time. Also, why use JavaScript for such a simple thing? And **jQuery**? Really?! This reminds me of [this image](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) :D

Comment: True True, well, thought he said he was unable to manipulate the hover of the `h2` element.  Suppose I should've read the entire question.  And LMFAO at that pic.  I don't think my answer is remotely tied into that question, he tagged the question with jQuery.